# Производительность наполнения DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Заметил интересную особенность, что если наполнять `DataTable` запросом, где фигурирует звездочка, то он наполняется на несколько секунд дольше, чем если указать явным образом **ВСЕ** колонки.

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Дело точно в том, что DataTable заполняется медленнее, а не в том, что медленнее выполняется запрос на сервере?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, возможно, поэтому я указал конкретную СУБД. Но разве для Sql Server есть какая-то разница, когда в обоих случаях возвращается одинаковое кол-во столбцов?

Comment: Ну я вам как раз намекаю на то, чтобы вы это выяснили самостоятельно и добавили в вопрос что "несмотря на то, что на сервере запрос выполняется с одинаковой скоростью". Сейчас вы в вопросе утверждаете, что скорость меняется именно на клиентской стороне — при заполнении DataTable

Comment: судя по моим замерам, когда явно заданы столбцы сервер выполняет запрос быстрее.

Comment: @Monomax, т.е. вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к C#, ADO.NET и прочим DataTable?

Comment: @АндрейNOP если судить по конкретно замеру времени получения данных в ManagmentSudio для MS SQL, время при явном задании столбцов меньше, но я не претендую на абсолютность ответа. Тут нужно заморочиться, и протестировать это все при различных условиях.  Признаться честно, на такие эксперименты времени жалко, так как я пока не встречался с вопросом об ускорении времени исполнения в этой части, но что-то мне подсказывает что выигрыш будет не значительным.

Comment: Стало интересно, погуглил. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2972032/5045688) пишут, что при указании звездочки sql server сперва должен запросить системную таблицу. Но без пруфов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, в принципе, доля правды в этом есть. Ведь * -это по сути синтаксический сахар, который скорее всего за кулисами разжевывается в перечисление всех колонок таблиц. Тогда странно, что при компиляции запроса он не лезет в табилцу, что бы узнать об наличии колонок.

Comment: @iluxa1810, почему странно? А если столбцы в таблице(ах) поменяются?